# Error when using subquery or parameter (but only when using both)

Tags: sql, excel, parameters, subquery

I'm stuck on a strange issue while using SQL queries in Excel.

There are three tables with data:

```
Table1            |  Table2            |  Table3
------            |  ------            |  ------
Field1    Field2  |  Field1    Field2  |  Field1    Field2    Field3
------            |  ------            |  ------    
item1     value1  |  item1     date11  |  item1     amount11  date1
item2     value2  |  item1     date12  |  item1     amount12  date2
item3     value3  |  item1     date13  |  item2     amount21  date3
                  |  item2     date21  |  item2     amount22  date4
                  |  item2     date22  |  item3     amount31  date5
                  |  item2     date23  |  item3     amount32  date6
                  |  item3     date31  |  
                  |  item3     date32  |  
                  |  item3     date33  |
```

What I need is the result:

```
item1     value1     date11     amount11+amount12
item2     value2     date23     amount21+amount22
item3     value3     date33     amount31+amount32
```

Where the third column contains the most recent date, so MAX (Table2.Field2), and where the fourth column is the sum of all the amounts, so SUM (Table3.Field2). However, I only need the results with dates from Table3 below an input date.

This is what I came up with:

```
SELECT
      Table1.Field1, Table1.Field2, (
      SELECT
            MAX (Table2.Field2) FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.Field1=Table1.Field1
      ), SUM (Table3.Field2)
FROM
      Table1, Table3
WHERE
      Table1.Field1=Table3.Field1 AND Table3.Field3<=?
GROUP BY
      Table1.Field1
```

This produces the following error:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The multi-part identifier "Table3.Field3" could not be bound.
```

The error is "resolved" if I do any of the following:

- Remove the subquery.
- Put the date directly in the query, i.e. replace Table3.Field3<=? by Table3.Field3<>'20140101' or any other date.

Neither of these is an option for me, so I'm kind of stuck.

Anyone who has any suggestions? :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can do all this with joins and aggregations:

```
select t1.field1, t1.field2, t2.date1, sum(t3.field2)
from table1 t1 join
     (select t2.field1, max(date1) as date1
      from table2 t2
      group by t2.field1
     ) t2
     on t1.field1 = t2.field1 join
     table3 t3
     on t1.field1 = t3.field1
group by t1.field1, t1.field2, t2.date1;
```